# c# ASP HttpWebRequest Multipart Upload XML and Images

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, httpwebrequest

I´ve (tried to) Customize a Method i found here on Stackoverflow to enable a Multipart Upload of one XML File and multiple Images, to process a HTTPWebRequest out a Sharepoint WebPart. For my shame i ve to say that I´m really not familar with that HttpRequest and StreamUpload thing, it`s the first time i seriously try to handle this.

Here`s my coding:

```
    public XmlDocument DoHttpUploadFile(string url, string[] file, string[] paramName, string[] contentType, NameValueCollection nvc, NameValueCollection headerItems, string xmlFileName)
    {
        var xmlDox = new XmlDocument();
        var totalLength = 0;
        string boundary = "---------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
        byte[] boundarybytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n");
        const string headerTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"\r\nContent-Type: {2}\r\n\r\n";

        // First Loop is just need to get the Length of all Parts

        for (int i = 0; i < file.Length; i++)
        {
            string header = "";
            if (i == 0)
            {
                header = string.Format(headerTemplate, paramName[i], xmlFileName, contentType[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                var filename = Path.GetFileName(file[i]);
                header = string.Format(headerTemplate, paramName[i], filename, contentType[i]);
            }

            byte[] headerbytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header);

            var headerLength = headerbytes.Length;
            var boundaryLength = boundarybytes.Length;

            totalLength = totalLength + headerLength + boundaryLength;

            if (file[i].StartsWith("<"))
            {
                byte[] xmlBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(file[i]);
                var xmlLength = xmlBytes.Length;
                totalLength = totalLength + xmlLength;
            }
            else
            {
                var client = new WebClient();
                var img = new Image { ImageUrl = file[i] };

                client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                // image as Byte into Stream
                var fileData = client.DownloadData(img.ImageUrl);
                var imgLength = fileData.Length;
                totalLength = totalLength + imgLength;
            }
        }

        var wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        wr.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
        wr.Method = "POST";
        wr.ContentLength = totalLength;

        Stream rs = wr.GetRequestStream();
        var read = 0;
        var finalLength = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < file.Length; i++)
        {
            string header = "";
            if(i==0)
            {
                header = string.Format(headerTemplate, paramName[i], xmlFileName, contentType[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                var filename = Path.GetFileName(file[i]);
                header = string.Format(headerTemplate, paramName[i], filename, contentType[i]);
            }

            rs.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);

            byte[] headerbytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header);

            var headerLength = headerbytes.Length;
            var boundaryLength = boundarybytes.Length;
            finalLength = finalLength + headerLength + boundaryLength;
            rs.Write(headerbytes, 0, headerbytes.Length);

            if(file[i].StartsWith("<"))
            {
                var writer = new StreamWriter(rs);
                byte[] xmlBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(file[i]);
                var xmlLength = xmlBytes.Length;
                finalLength = finalLength + xmlLength;
                writer.Write(file[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                var getitem = new GetItemFromList();

                var client = new WebClient();
                var img = new Image {ImageUrl = file[i]};

                client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                // image as Byte into Stream
                var fileData = client.DownloadData(img.ImageUrl);
                finalLength = finalLength + fileData.Length;
                rs.Write(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
            }

        }

        finalLength.ToString();
rs.Close(); // Here it stops with Exception 'Bytes are not completely written



        WebResponse wresp = null;
        try
        {
            wresp = wr.GetResponse();
            var wrlength = wr.ContentLength;
            var stream2 = wresp.GetResponseStream();
            if (stream2 != null)
            {
                var reader2 = new StreamReader(stream2);
                var backstr = reader2.ReadToEnd();

                xmlDox.LoadXml(backstr);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //log.Error("Error uploading file", ex);
            if (wresp != null) 
                wresp.Close();
            wresp = null;
        }
        finally
        {
            wr = null;            }

        return xmlDox;
    }
```

It Stops at rs.Close with the Exception 'Cannot Close Stream bytes are not writen complete'.

I thought maybe this depends on wr.ContentLength and tried to set this manually, as you can see in the above section of the coding.

I cant find a solution i tried the last two Day`s and searched all around the web, especially stackeOverflow.

So, if anyone could tell me what going wrong, pleeeease tell me, thx.

Answer (score 0):

"The Exception is thrown because you are writing less bytes than the WebRequest expects. For example if you have set say 75 bytes in the ContentLength property and you write 69 bytes on the ResquestStream and close it the exception will be thrown."

See this post: [Cannot close stream until all bytes are written](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441370/cannot-close-stream-until-all-bytes-are-written)

Can you check the size of TotalLength making sure you are using the byte length and verify in a debugger?