# C# cannot close stream until all bytes are written

Tags: c#, httplistener

I wrote a mock c# http server and I have a problem. When the client first closes the connection (all data for the response have been received), my program throws an exception:

> *InvalidOperationException: Cannot close stream until all bytes are
>   written.*

What should I do? Does it mean the server socket is closed too?

Comment: Maybe reading [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441370/cannot-close-stream-until-all-bytes-are-written) will give you some idea.

Answer (score 0):

Did the server read the entire request?

It is generally a good practice to close your side of the connection, then read until you get zero bytes (this means the other side closed the connection), then free the socket.

```
private void SafeShutdown( Socket s )
{
    socket.Shutdown( Send );
    var buff = new byte[200];
    while( socket.Receive( buff ) > 0 )
        ;
    socket.Shutdown( Receive );
    socket.Close();
}
```